# Why is 6-7 threads faster than 20?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, stdthread

In school we were introduced to C++11 threads. The teacher gave us a simple assessment to complete which was to make a basic web crawler using 20 threads. To me threading is pretty new, although I do understand the basics.

I would like to mention that I am not looking for someone to complete my assessment as it is already done. I only want to understand the reason why using 6 threads is always faster than using 20.

Please see code sample below.

main.cpp:

```
do
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread(SweepUrlList);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    WriteToConsole();
    listUrl = listNewUrl;
    listNewUrl.clear();
} while (listUrl.size() != 0);
```

Basically this assigns to each worker thread the job to complete which is the method **SweepUrlList** that can be found below and then join all thread.

```
while (1)
{
    mutextGetNextUrl.lock();
    std::set<std::string>::iterator it = listUrl.begin();
    if (it == listUrl.end())
    {
        mutextGetNextUrl.unlock();
        break;
    }
    std::string url(*it);
    listUrl.erase(*it);
    mutextGetNextUrl.unlock();
    ExtractEmail(url, listEmail);
    std::cout << ".";
}
```

So each worker thread loop until ListUrl is empty. **ExtractEmail** is a method that downloads the webpage (using curl) and parse it to extract emails from mailto links.
The only blocking call in **ExtractEmail** can be found below:

```
if(email.length() != 0)
{
    mutextInsertNewEmail.lock();
    ListEmail.insert(email);
    mutextInsertNewEmail.unlock();
}
```

All answers are welcome and if possible links to any documentation you found to answer this question.

Comment: Were you using 20 cores or 6 cores?

Comment: You should probably do some profiling to determine where the threads spend the time. You could also try replacing `ExtractEmail` with a sleep and see what happens then. Since you're not showing a complete program ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it may be very hard to answer this question here.

Comment: I have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.9GHz

Comment: Other important details would be speed of the network connection to the target URLs, and what is in between, and also the amount of total data downloaded. My guess at a reason would be something like a (possibly transparent) proxy which doesn't like you doing 20 connections rapidly. It could also be that the target web site does throttling when it sees you doing too many connections at once, if all URLs point to the same web site.

Comment: If there was only one core, it would make next to no difference to 6-20 web crawlers that are all network-bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly universal problem with threading, and at its core:

What you are demonstrating is thread [Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)). The operating system is going to work with the various threads, and schedule work where there is currently not work.

Assuming you have 4 cores and hyper threading you have 8 processors that can carry the load, but also that of other applications (Operating System, C++ debugger, and your application to start).

In theory, you would probably be OK on performance up until about 8 intensive threads. After you reach the most threads your processor can effectively use, then threads begin to compete against each other for resources. This can be seen (especially with intensive applications and tight loops) by poor performance.

Finally, this is a simplified answer but I suspect what you are seeing.

Comment: But these threads aren't intensive. Anything coming from a web server behind a network is going to look glacial to an i7 (as long it only needs textual processing).

Comment: I was thinking on that too, actually. And I still think that it has to do with scheduling, and your loops and possibly wait states constantly occurring in the connections. All I am able to do right now is speculate (although apparently others speculated mush as I did).

Comment: I should also mention that using 6 threads gives an average of ~10% CPU utilization. At 20 threads CPU is at 100%.

Comment: @MaxVerro If that is 10x CPU utilization *with less work getting done* with 20 threads (as implied by your question title), then there's bad code (even a bug) somewhere, like a polling busy loop waiting for some resource. You should then try to figure out what the program actually does, where it spends all that CPU, if it's not doing useful work.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is choke points. Something that you are doing is causing a choke point. When this occurs there is a slow down. It could be in the number of active connections you are making to something, or merely the extra overhead of the number and memory size of the threads (see the below answer about cores being one of these chokes).

You will need to set up a series of monitors to investigate where your choke point is, and what needs to change in order to achieve scale. Many systems across every industry face this problem every day. Opening up the throttle at one end does not equal the same increase in the output at the other end. In cases it can decrease the output at the other end.

Take for example individuals leaving a hall. The goal is to get 100 people out of the building as quickly as possible. If single file produces a rate of 1 person every 1 second therefore 100 seconds to clear the building. We many be able to half that time by sending them out 2 abreast, so 50 seconds to clear the building. What if we then sent them out as 8 abreast. The door is only 2m wide, so with 8 abreast being equivalent to 4m, only 50% of the first row would make it through. The other 4 would then cause a blockage for the next row and so on. Depending on the rate, this could cause temporary blockages and increase the time 10 fold.

Comment: Choke point here is mostly likely something outside his computer or at least outside his program. A proxy, a crappy router, or a web server, something which reacts poorly to 20 simultaneous network connections.

Comment: @hyde - yup, that would be my guess too.  All that stuff in the other answers about scheduling and context-changes is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are an operating system construct. Basically, each thread's state (which is basically all the CPU's registers and virtual memory mapping [which is a part of the process construct]) is saved by the operating system. Once the OS gives that specific thread "execution time" it restores this state and let it run. Once this time is finished, it has to save this state. The process of saving a specific thread's state and restoring another is called [Context Switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), and it takes a significant amount of time (usually between a couple of hundreds to thousand of CPU cycles).

There are also additional penalties to context switching. Some of the processor's cache (like the virtual memory translation cache, called the [TLB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer)) has to be flushed, pipelining instruction to be discarded and more. Generally, you want to minimize context switching as much as possible.

If your CPU has 4 cores, than 4 threads can run simultaneously. If you try to run 20 threads on a 4 core system, then the OS has to manage time between those threads so it will seem like they run in parallel. E.g, threads 1-4 will run for 50 milliseconds, then 5-9 will run for 50 milliseconds, etc.

Therefore, if all of your threads are running CPU intensive operations, it is generally most efficient to make your program use the same amount of threads as cores (sometimes called 'processors' in windows). If you have more threads than cores, than context switching must happen, and it is overhead that can be minimized.

Comment: The question code claims to download stuff from network. That's probably not CPU bound.

Comment: You are right I am not CPU bound. Each thread will download a webpage using curl and parse it and so on until the set containing the urls is empty

Comment: How about network-bound? Too many connections might cause lower bandwidth. You should check your CPU usage, hard disk usage and network usage during your program's operation.

Answer (score 0):

In general, more threads is not better. More threading provides value in two ways higher parallelism and less blocking. More threading hurts by higher memory, higher context switching and higher resource contention.

The value of more threads for higher parallelism is generally maximized between 1-2x the number of actual cores that you have available. If your threads are already CPU bound the maximum value is generally 1x number of cores.

The value of less blocking is much harder to quantify and depends on the type of work you are performing. If you are IO bound and your threads are primarily waiting for IO to be ready then a larger number of threads could be beneficial.

However if you have shared state between threads, or you are doing some form of message passing between threads then you will run into synchronization and contention issues. As the number of threads increases, the more these types of overhead as well as context switches dominates the time spent doing your task.

[Amdahl's law](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) is a useful measure to determine if higher parallelism will actually improve the total runtime of your job.

You also must be careful that your increased parallelism doesn't exceed some other resource like total memory or disk or network throughput. Once you have saturated the current bottleneck, you will not see improved performance by increasing the number of threads.

Before doing any performance tuning, it is important to understand what the dominant resource bottleneck is. There are lots of tools for doing system-wide resource monitoring. On Linux, one very useful tool is `dstat`. On Windows, you can use the Task Manager to monitor many of these resources.